# Given only source file, what files does it import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm building a dependency graph in python3 using the `ast` module. How do I know what file(s) will be imported if that import statement were to be executed?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but here are some bits you should be aware of:

- Imports might happen in conditional or try-catch blocks. So depending on a setting of an environment variable, module A might or might not import module B.
- There's a wide variety of import syntax: `import A`, `from A import B`, `from A import *`, `from . import A`, `from .. import A`, `from ..A import B` as well as their versions with `A` replaced with sub-modules.
- Imports can happen in any executable context - the top-level of the file, in a function, in a class definition etc.
- `eval` can evaluate code with imports. Up to you if you consider such code to be a dependency.

The standard library [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/modulefinder.html) module might help.

Comment: You have to consider dynamic imports which your above doesn't do:  consider the following:
`path, task_name = "module.function".rsplit(".", 1); module = importlib.import_module(path);real_func = getattr(module, task_name); real_func();` The actual original string could be obfuscated, or pulled from a DB, or a file or ....

Comment: It looks like `modulefinder` works by importing files, which is not an option for me. `eval` is `evil`, so I'm not going to care about imports in `eval`s :) Import syntax should be handled by the `ast` module down to two cases: `import` and `importFrom`. If something imports a module in a function, in an if-statement or such, it's a dependency afaict.

Comment: @Jmons yup, the answer wasn't close to complete. Definitely add it as a separate answer, because I think it's valuable for people to see it.

Comment: @FilipHaglund I think then it depends on what your use case is, in the end. You can definitely have the "safest-set" of imports, which would be absolutely everything which appears in import or importFrom. You might get foo.windows and foo.linux both that way, or foo.compiled and foo.not_compiled, but you'd have _something_. But if you need a more precise listing, you might not be able to skip actually executing bits of the files.

Comment: @FilipHaglund oh, you want to know what file on disk you'd actually get from a certain import?

Comment: @HoriaComan yes, so I can load that into the `ast` module and continue walking to build my graph :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment: the other answers are valid, but one of the fundamental problems is that your examples only work for 'simple' scripts or files: A lot of more complex code will use things like dynamic imports: consider the following:

```
path, task_name = "module.function".rsplit(".", 1);
module = importlib.import_module(path);
real_func = getattr(module, task_name); 
real_func();
```

The actual original string could be obfuscated, or pulled from a DB, or a file or...

There are alternatives to importlib, but this is on top of the exec type stuff you might see in @horia's good answer.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I'd say the eval rule applies here as well; if you're doing too complex imports, I'll just not find them.